# Django - How to chain two querysets in such a way that's efficient and preserves ordering

Tags: django, django-queryset

What's the best way to chain two querysets together? I've tried using itertools.chain() and bitwise OR.

The problem I have with chain() is that it doesn't play well with pagination. Because chain() returns a list, I get "Exception Value: 'list' object has no attribute '_clone'" when used with Django's pagination.

Bitwise OR is okay, but it doesn't seem to preserve the ordering. The two querysets just seem to be combined. I need the items of the first queryset to be placed before the items of the second queryset.

Comment: `chain` doesn't return a `list`, it returns a `chain`. None of the `itertools` functions / classes return a sequence, they all return iterables.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is simple solution for that problem. Following solution will work like a charm, but it's not simple.

Define your own QuerySum class in following way:

```
class QuerySum(object):
    def __init__(self, queries):
        self.queries = queries

    def _clone(self, queries):
        return QuerySum(q._clone() for q in self.queries)

    def __len__(self, queries):
        return sum(len(q) for q in self.queries)

    # you should define rest of the methods that paginator uses in similar manner
```

Use this implementation to chain queries.